# Ember: how to handle unexpected routes?

Tags: ember.js

The router nicely treats the URL and results in calling the appropriate route if the route exists.  But how to handle the case where the route does not exist ?

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('about', { path: "/about" });
  this.resource('admin', { path: "/admin" });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
      <h1>ABOUT</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="admin">
      <h1>ADMIN</h1>
</script>
```

**Use case:**

When a user enters the URL index.html#/xxxx, I would like to transition to a sort of error page indicating that the requested "page" does not exit.

So far, I did not found a solution ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a catch all Route like this:

```
this.route('missing', { path: "/*path" });
```

Then redirect within this route. My implementation looks like the following:

```
App.MissingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect : function(){
        App.LOG.warn("No Route for given URL found. Will transition to Index Route instead.");
        this.transitionTo("index");
    }
});
```

Comment: Great solution. A pitty that this is not really documented (as far as I know).

Comment: The current documentation mentions it here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_wildcard-globbing-routes

Answer (score 3):

[Ember.JS: How to handle invalid URLs](http://dinethmendis.com/blog/2013/7/30/handling-unsupported-urls-with-emberjs) is a good example if you're looking for another approach.

Comment: Good description of the solution !